# The difference between select * where id = :id and entity manager find()

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, hql, jpql

I know that both

```
EntityManager.createQuery("select e from Entity e where e.id = :id")
```

and:

```
EntityManager.find(Entity.class,id)
```

returns the same result but, I really want to know the difference between them.

Comment: em.find() won't execute any query if the entity has been loaded in the first-level cache already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They produce the same SQL too.

There was a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679264/different-sql-using-find-and-createquery-from-hibernate-entity-manager) about the possibility to generate different SQL in some cases, but nothing different was found.

The differences stay in how they can help you in different cases, but only at the code level:

- The `createQuery` requires a JPQL/HQL to work. Any change on the `id` column name or entity name will affect the query string. The `find` method not suffer of the same problem.
- You need more boilerplate code to work with `createQuery` (`Query` class, call `setParameter` method, query String, etc).